# Game Center Like Button

Tags: iphone, ios, game-center

I am currently working on an app with Game Center integration. I have noticed that in the match lobby of Game Center there is a Like-button for Facebook. This buttons seems very helpful, and I know how to enable it (logging in on Facebook). But how does Game Center know which page the user likes? Can I specify a Facebook-page to like?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

looks like you have to include your Facebook account into your device.

http://pilotaz.blogspot.nl/2013/01/game-center-facebook-like-unavailable.html